# Erro ao passar caminho do subrelatorio do JasperReports

Tags: servlet, jasper-reports, jasper, jaspersoft-studio

Boa tarde pessoal, estou com um problema não estou conseguindo passar o caminho do subrelatorio para o relatório principal. Irei o código que fiz até agora, por favor me ajudem, não sei o que estou fazendo de errado.
Por favor sejam especificos, pois não tenho experiencia com o JasperReports.
Estou usando o Jasper Studio e o Jasper na versão 5.0.1

Erro:

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlDigesterFactory).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Resource not found at : debitos.jasper
    at net.sf.jasperreports.repo.RepositoryUtil.getResourceFromLocation(RepositoryUtil.java:255)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.repo.RepositoryUtil.getReport(RepositoryUtil.java:208)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillSubreport.evaluateReport(JRFillSubreport.java:328)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillSubreport.evaluateSubreport(JRFillSubreport.java:361)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillSubreport.evaluate(JRFillSubreport.java:286)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillElementContainer.evaluate(JRFillElementContainer.java:259)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillBand.evaluate(JRFillBand.java:459)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillColumnBand(JRVerticalFiller.java:2044)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillDetail(JRVerticalFiller.java:778)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReportStart(JRVerticalFiller.java:288)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReport(JRVerticalFiller.java:151)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:909)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:841)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.fill(JRFiller.java:88)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fill(JasperFillManager.java:653)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperFillManager.java:969)
    at br.com.loov.mycash.relatorio.GeradorRelatorio.geraPdf(GeradorRelatorio.java:35)
    at br.com.loov.mycash.controller.RelatorioMensalController.doGet(RelatorioMensalController.java:49)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at br.com.loov.mycash.filtro.LoginFiltro.doFilter(LoginFiltro.java:47)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:494)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:651)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:412)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:754)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1385)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Classe que Gera o Relatorio:

```
package br.com.loov.mycash.relatorio;

import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.Map;

import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRExporter;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRExporterParameter;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperPrint;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperReport;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter;

public class GeradorRelatorio {

    private JRBeanCollectionDataSource jrBeanCollectionDataSource;

    public GeradorRelatorio() {

    }

    public GeradorRelatorio(JRBeanCollectionDataSource jrBeanCollectionDataSource) {
        this.jrBeanCollectionDataSource = jrBeanCollectionDataSource;
    }

    public void geraPdf(String jrxml, 
        Map<String, Object> parametros, OutputStream saida) {

        try {
            // compila jrxml em memoria
            JasperReport jasper = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(jrxml);

            // preenche relatorio
            JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasper, parametros, this.jrBeanCollectionDataSource);

            // exporta para pdf
            JRExporter exporter = new JRPdfExporter();
            exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, print);
            exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_STREAM, saida);

            exporter.exportReport();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }   
}
```

Controller do relatorio:

```
package br.com.loov.mycash.controller;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.batch.Main;

import br.com.loov.mycash.dao.ContaDAO;
import br.com.loov.mycash.model.Conta;
import br.com.loov.mycash.relatorio.GeradorRelatorio;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRParameter;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.FileResolver;

@WebServlet("/RelatorioMensalController")
public class RelatorioMensalController extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private ContaDAO dao = new ContaDAO();

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        int idUsuario = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("idUsuario"));
        System.out.println(idUsuario);
        // acha jrxml dentro da aplicação
        ServletContext contexto = request.getServletContext();
        String jrxml = contexto.getRealPath("relatorio/relatorioMensal.jrxml");
        String jasper = contexto.getRealPath("relatorio/");

        // prepara parâmetros
        Map<String, Object> parametros = new HashMap<>();

        parametros.put("SUBREPORT_DIR",jasper);


        // gera relatório
        List<Conta> listaConta = dao.listar(idUsuario);
        GeradorRelatorio gerador = new GeradorRelatorio(new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(listaConta));
        gerador.geraPdf(jrxml, parametros, response.getOutputStream());

    }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        doGet(request, response);
    }

}
```

Link do git onde está o codigo do relatorio: [Link](https://github.com/JessPergentino/relatorio.git)

[image: Project Explorer]

[image: Relatorio]

Comment: amigo por que voce não passa o relatorio ja compilado? ainda vai e compila o jrxml para depois o exibir, eu recomendo que teste os relatorios compilados em jasper

Comment: você acha q é por isso que não está achando o subrelatorio?

Comment: Fiz como vc sugeriu mais ainda assim não está funcionando. Aqui está o repositorio onde estão o projeto e o relatorio: https://github.com/JessPergentino/relatorio

Comment: vo importar  e testar no eclipse

Answer (score 0):

Meu caro dentro do parametro **SUBREPORT_DIR** set o seguinte valor :

```
this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("").getFile()
```

Vai recuperar a partir do classLoader o diretorio raiz do seu projeto, testei com o arquivo do git e funcionou perfeitamente.